How to exclude some file extensions from ActivityResultContracts.OpenMultipleDocuments()
How to exclude some file extensions from ActivityResultContracts.OpenMultipleDocuments()
I have some list of extensions which user not allowed to select in document chooser.
How can I manage selection with excluded extensions?
val documentLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenMultipleDocuments()) {
            if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                composeViewModel.onFilePathsListChange(
                    list = it,
                    context = context
                )
            }
            onClose()
        }

    SideEffect {
        documentLauncher.launch(
            arrayOf("*/*")  //
        )
    }

